# Wanted to remove property name while printing the log in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Here I have one doubt
I am creating log mediator in WSO2 and setting one property msg and it gives me output as follows

```
[2017-08-04 18:13:10,041] []  INFO - LogMediator Msg = Msg Coming************************
```

Here I just want the output like Msg Coming************************ I dont want to print property name...
How I will able to do it..

Comment: Type nothing (empty string) in quotas ?

Comment: <log description="" level="headers">
        <property name="msg" value="Messsage coming****************"/>
    </log>                                                                                                                                the above is my code but if I put nothing in quotes instead of "msg" it is giving me error while saving.

Comment: Hm, actually it not possible. Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Entry name is a required attribute for a Log property

Comment: So is there any other way we can do it?

Comment: You can write you own custom log mediator.

Comment: Can you show me example for the same?

Comment: why don't you give name to property as ****************. For value use xpath translate function

Comment: I am not getting it.It will be very helpful if you can provide some example.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
  <property name="*******************" value="hello" />
```

or

```
  <property name="*******************" expression="translate('some string to log', 'abcdefg.....z', '****************************')" />
```

In first case you will get  unknown property, in second unkond property with unknown value. Why you need such logging

Comment: This is just a sample ex.The actual logs are different with different properties.I have posted this example as I can not post the original one. Just need to know can we achieve to print logs without property name.